# Multimarkdown table formatting in Vim

Tags: vim, markdown

I've recently moved from using TextMate to using Vim a lot more (because I split my time between Mac and Linux). One thing I miss is the wonderful MultiMarkdown bundle which, amongst other features, lets me enter tables in MultiMarkdown syntax and then reformats them so they look pretty.

So, for example this:

```
| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading 3 |
| --: | -- | -- |
| 1 | Some text | Some other text |
| 2 | A somewhat longer piece of text | Further text |
```

Becomes this:

```
| Heading 1 | Heading 2                       | Heading 3       |
| --------: | ------------------------------- | --------------- |
|         1 | Some text                       | Some other text |
|         2 | A somewhat longer piece of text | Further text    |
```

The closest thing I've found to this is [table_format.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=857), but it's pretty old and uses spaces instead of vertical bars to delimit columns.

Is there anything better out there to reformat tables like these in Vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin can table-format by vertical bars using the shortcut "\t|".

Comment: That's great, thanks. It looks like that plugin will be handy formatting LaTeX documents too.

Comment: You are welcome. I use Align all the time. I just love table formatting.

Answer (score 7):

I've also now come across [Tabular.vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) which is another plugin along the same lines as Align.vim. They're similar but each have advantages and disadvantages in how they work.

Comment: It's an old question BUT Vimcasts has an excellent podcast on using tabular.vim here: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Answer (score 3):

I think [vim-table-mode](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode) may be more powerful. 
It will format table when inserting vertical bar "|", and can generate tables with many styles, not just Markdown.